# SSIS and Access to Azure Key Vault for Column Encryption

Tags: azure, encryption, ssis, azure-keyvault

Has anyone seen a way to use Azure Key Vault with SSIS.  I have a database table that has been set up with column encryption on one of the columns.  The Column Encryption key is in Azure Key Vault.  What I want to do is process a file coming and and save to the table.  The trick is getting the data encrypted for the one column.  I have seen the Azure Key Vault Provider but not sure I could do this within SSIS.